# Get data from one table with foreign_table and update to another in TCA

Tags: typo3

I'm modifying an image upload extension and I'm working on a feature where images can be placed in categories.

Right now the categories are listed in a select field that uses foreign_table to get the categories from a table (called tx_gallery_categories) and when saved the category Id (the value in the option field) is saved to table called tx_gallery_items.

But that column is no longer needed (i was wrong the first time). Depending on what category you choose I want TCA to update a table called tx_gallery_itemsCategory and set the categoryId where itemId is equal to the saved images uid

Here is the TCA (i have removed all other columns beside categoryId) and categoryId is the one I want to move out from this, I think, and in to it's own TCA which is connected to tx_gallery_itemsCategory:

```
$TCA["tx_gallery_items"] = array (
"ctrl" => $TCA["tx_gallery_items"]["ctrl"],
"interface" => array (
    "showRecordFieldList" => "hidden,oid,filename, videoembedcode,caption"
),
"feInterface" => $TCA["tx_gallery_items"]["feInterface"],
"columns" => array (
    "categoryId" => Array (     
        "exclude" => 1,     
        "label" => "LLL:EXT:gc_gallery/locallang_db.xml:tx_gallery_items.categories",       
        "config" => Array (
            "type" => "select",
            "foreign_table" => "tx_gallery_categories",
            // "foreign_table_where" => " true"
            // "itemsProcFunc" => "tx_gallery_getImageCategories->getCategories"
            // 'default' => '123'
        )
    ),
),
"types" => array (
    "0" => array("showitem" => "hidden, oid, filename, categoryId, videoembedcode, caption, linkpid")
)
);

$TCA["tx_gallery_categories"] = array (
"ctrl" => $TCA["tx_gallery_categories"]["ctrl"],
"interface" => array (
    "showRecordFieldList" => "categoryTitle"
),
"feInterface" => $TCA["tx_gallery_categories"]["feInterface"],
"columns" => array (
    "categoryTitle" => Array (      
        "exclude" => 0,     
        "label" => "LLL:EXT:gc_gallery/locallang_db.xml:tx_gallery_items.categories",       
        "config" => Array (
            "type" => "text",
            "cols" => "30", 
            "rows" => "5",
        )
    )
),
"types" => array (
    "0" => array("showitem" => "categoryTitle")
)
```

);

But instead of it working like that I want to save the images uid from tx_gallery_items to another table called tx_gallery_itemsCategory which is a many to many table between tx_gallery_items and tx_gallery_categories

Here are the tables:

```
tx_gallery_items:
  uid | pid | ... (and many more but only uid is relevant)
  432 | 34  | ...

tx_gallery_itemsCategory:
  id | itemId | categoryId
  1  | 432    | 1

tx_gallery_categories:
  uid | pid | categoryTitle   
  1   | 34  | example category
```

And here is the ext_tables.php

```
$TCA["tx_gallery_items"] = array (
"ctrl" => array (
    'title'     => 'LLL:EXT:gc_gallery/locallang_db.xml:tx_gallery_items',
    'label'     => 'filename',
    'tstamp'    => 'tstamp',
    'crdate'    => 'crdate',
    'cruser_id' => 'cruser_id',
    'sortby' => 'sorting',
    'delete' => 'deleted',
    'enablecolumns' => array (
        'disabled' => 'hidden',
    ),
    'dynamicConfigFile' => t3lib_extMgm::extPath($_EXTKEY).'tca.php',
    'iconfile'          => t3lib_extMgm::extRelPath($_EXTKEY).'icon_tx_gallery_items.gif',
),
"feInterface" => array (
    "fe_admin_fieldList" => "hidden, oid, filename, category, videoembedcode, caption, linkpid, categoryId",
)
);

$TCA["tx_gallery_categories"] = array (
"ctrl" => array (
    'title'     => 'LLL:EXT:gc_gallery/locallang_db.xml:tx_gallery_items',
    'label'     => 'categoryTitle',
    'tstamp'    => 'tstamp',
    'sortby' => 'sorting',
    'delete' => 'deleted',
    // 'enablecolumns' => array (
        // 'disabled' => 'hidden',
    // ),
    'dynamicConfigFile' => t3lib_extMgm::extPath($_EXTKEY).'tca.php',
    'iconfile'          => t3lib_extMgm::extRelPath($_EXTKEY).'icon_tx_gallery_items.gif',
),
// "feInterface" => array (
    // "fe_admin_fieldList" => "uid, pid, categoryTitle, categoryDescription, tstamp, sorting, deleted, hidden, categorySlug",
// )
);
```

So my question is (i think) how can I get the uid from the current image the user is editing and save it to another table.

This is my first try with TCA and I'm very confused on how all this is connected.
I hope that anyone knows this better than me :)
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is the hook concept implemented in the tcemain component. There is one called `processDatamap_postProcessFieldArray` which is invoked when any record is saved in the backend. Thus, you can check whether it's "yours" and do your other queries or whatever you want to change.

There is [an example](http://typo3.org/documentation/article/how-to-use-existing-hooks-in-your-own-extension/) of how to use this feature. Although it is pretty old, it should still be working that way.